# Program that ANDs two values between 0 and 255 does not return the ANDed bits (in Boolean)

Tags: python, binary

I am working on this code challenge:

> Get two numbers (0-255) from the user and perform the bitwise AND operation. Output the two input numbers and the result in 8-digit binary representation.

In my code each boolean value is used as a representation of one binary bit, so `[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]` would be 10000000. In the `produce_string` function, the decimal number is being converted into its binary form. Then in the `write_string` function, I am trying to change the values of the array from boolean to 1s or 0s. For example if the array is `[False, False, False, True]` then it should be `"0001"` after the function is called.

**The problem** is that the printed result is always `[ True False False False False False False False]` in boolean, instead of `"1000110"`, no matter what input I gave. Where did I go wrong?

I thought it had to do with the `produce_string` function, but I tried multiple variations of it and it led me nowhere.

My code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
a, b, n = 0, 0, 0
abool = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  dtype=bool)
bbool = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  dtype=bool)``
cbool = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  dtype=bool)
booleanString = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  dtype=bool)

def produce_string(x):
    for i  in range(0,7):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            booleanString[n] = True
        else:
            booleanString[n] = False
        x = math.trunc(x/2)
        
def write_string(booleanString):
    for i in range(0, 7):
        if booleanString[7-n]:
            booleanString[n] = '1'
        else:
            booleanString[n] = '1'
    return booleanString

a = int(input("First value (between 0 and 255): "))
b = int(input("Second value (between 0 and 255): "))
produce_string(a)
abool = booleanString
produce_string(b)
bbool = booleanString
for i in range(0,7):
    cbool[n] = abool[n] and bbool[n]
print("First value: ", write_string(abool))
print("Second value: ", write_string(bbool))
print("First value AND second value: ", write_string(cbool))
```

Comment: Why do you not just use `a & b`? This looks approximately 800% too complicated.

Comment: `for i in range:` and then you always use `n` (which is always zero) in the loop body, both in `write_string` and in the main loop!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you never use `i` in your loops, and use index `n` instead -- which will have the same value in each iteration of those loops.

Your ranges should also have a span of 8 instead of 7.

Some other remarks:

- You should not do a float division with `/`, but integer division with `//`. No more need for `math.trunc` then.
- I don't see the utility of `numpy` here: unless you use numpy methods, this is not going to benefit anything.
- Avoid using global variables. Where you still need them, don't have them mutated inside functions.
- I would suggest storing the booleans in reverse order, instead of doing the reversal when converting to a string.
- Although I get why you used the name `string` in your functions, it is quite  common to only use that term for *character* strings, not boolean "strings". So I would change those function names.
- Although you don't really need the arrays of booleans, I assume this is part of the exercise, so I left them in.

With some use of native Python features -- like `map`, `join`, `zip` and comprehension, you'd get this:

```
def produce_booleans(x):
    return [(x >> i) % 2 == 1 for i in range(7, -1, -1)]

def to_string(booleans):
    return "".join(map(str, map(int, booleans)))

a = int(input("First value (between 0 and 255): "))
b = int(input("Second value (between 0 and 255): "))
abool = produce_booleans(a)
bbool = produce_booleans(b)
cbool = [a and b for a, b in zip(abool, bbool)]
print("First value: ", to_string(abool))
print("Second value: ", to_string(bbool))
print("First value AND second value: ", to_string(cbool))
```

However, the bitwise AND (`&`) operator will work on all binary bits in `int` operands, so you don't really need the boolean arrays/lists. Instead, apply the `&` operator directly on the two input `int` values. Then it is only a matter of outputting the binary format with 8 digits. For that you can use `:08b` as a formatting option in an f-string:

```
a = int(input("First value (between 0 and 255): "))
b = int(input("Second value (between 0 and 255): "))
print(f"First value: {a:08b}")
print(f"Second value: {b:08b}")
print(f"First value AND second value: {a&b:08b}")
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt really need the array of booleans, but I just thought it would be easier to use them and then convert them into  numbers. Regardless, thank you for the help.

Comment: OK, in that case, it can be done much easier. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = int(input("First value (between 0 and 255): "))
b = int(input("Second value (between 0 and 255): "))
abin = bin(a).replace("0b","").zfill(8)
bbin = bin(b).replace("0b","").zfill(8)
cbin = ''
for i in range(8):
    cbin += '1' if abin[i] == '1' and bbin[i] == '1' else '0'
print("First value:  ", abin)
print("Second value: ", bbin)
print("First value AND second value: ", cbin)
```